# PyMongo and Docker-Compose; Cannot insert a document

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, pymongo

Trying to insert a test document into a test collection in python using a MongoDB server.

docker-compose.yml (straight from docs on https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo)

```
# Use root/example as user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/
```

python (straight from docs on https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html)

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

# Connect to MongoDB
client = MongoClient('mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017/')

# Connect to database
db = client['test']

# Connect to collection
collection = db['test']

# Insert document
collection.insert_one({"name": "John", "age": 30})

print("test complete")
```

I have ran docker-compose up and successfully can view the mongo-express server contents. I stepped through every part with a debugger and it halts on collection.insert. Where am I going wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add

```
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

to the docker-compose,
and it now successfully inserts :)